# How can I create a debit card online outside of the US?

Tags: debit-card, paypal, israel

How can I create a debit card **online** outside of the US?

There are no convenient ways to create a debit card in my area. I want to buy some stuff online and I'm afraid for my credit card security.

I can't use PayPal because it doesn't accept my CC for some reason. If you know a third party service that allows you to transfer money from your credit card to your PayPal, let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: Based on your profile, I tagged this question with the Israel; please correct it if this is incorrect.

Comment: This is correct, but as I said, there are no convenient ways to create a debit card in my area.

Comment: I tagged your question with a location because even if there aren't convenient ways to create a debit card in your area, there *may* be online services that are specific to a given location (and adding a location doesn't *detract* from the question, in my opinion).

Comment: What is an online debit card and what does it mean to _create_ one? In the US, a debit card allows the merchant to have money deducted from the cardholder's _bank account_ and sent to the merchant's account (less any fees charged by the bank/card company), and a debit card is "created" by opening a bank account that offers debit cards. Also, credit cards come with protections that debit cards do not. Given the choice between giving an untrusted merchant a debit card versus a credit card, I would vastly prefer the latter, or even better. to get a one-time use number from my credit card company.

Comment: Still nothing on this?

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean "There are no convenient ways to create a debit card in my area"? Of course there is. At any [post office](http://www.israelpost.co.il/postshirut.nsf/misparid/163?OpenDocument).